# How to create a pull request for a particular commit

Tags: git, cherry-pick

I am trying to create a pull request for a particular commit. I have already executed the following commands

```
git push upstream issue-430
```

There is a particular commit that I want to create a pull request. 
I tried to create another branch from issue-430 and cherry pick the particular commit but it is giving the error

```
error: your local changes would be overwritten by cherry-pick.
hint: commit your changes or stash them to proceed.
fatal: cherry-pick failed
```

But I already committed all my local changes.

Comment: What is the output of `git status` in your local repository?

Comment: It gives 
    no changes added to commit

Comment: I feel that the issue lies in the fact that I already pushed the commit to remote

Comment: The message says: `hint: commit your changes or stash them to proceed.` You must not have local changes. Just follow the hint and it should work.

Answer (score 0):

> I tried to create another branch from issue-430

This is a problem — you created a branch from `issue-430` (say it's called `newbranch`), which means that any commits made in `issue-430` are already in `new-branch`. When you branch off another branch, it's almost like creating a copy of where you branched from (not really because it's actually just creating another pointer to the same hash but for understanding sake we'll go with this). So you're trying to cherry pick commits from `issue-430` onto `new-branch` but they're already there because `new-branch` is the same as `issue-430`, so you can't commit anything because git says there's no changes to apply.

You probably also have modified changes that show up when running `git status`, and those modified files, git is saying, will be overwritten if you try to apply the changes from the commit you're cherry-picking.

So instead, say you want to make a PR to `master` from a specific commit from `issue-430`. First, make sure you don't have any relevant uncommitted changes (you can `git stash` to push them off for now)

Checkout `master` **first** and branch off that, say we call it `pr-branch`. Then, cherry-pick that one commit onto `pr-branch`. Then, push `pr-branch` to your upstream repo.